# Xamarin: ListView Group Header With CheckBox

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, syncfusion

In application I have a ListView bound to some data, and it has  been grouped.I need a checkbox in group header once the group header checkbox has been selected all the data below a group has to be selected. I have added a checkbox to to the grouping header like

```
<xFormsListView:SfListView x:Name="SpecialityDiseaseListView"
                           itemsSource="{Binding SuggestionDiseaseList}" 
                           ItemSize="40" SelectionBackgroundColor="Transparent">
<xFormsListView:SfListView.DataSource>
    <dataSource:DataSource>
        <dataSource:DataSource.GroupDescriptors>
            <dataSource:GroupDescriptor PropertyName="GroupHeading"/>
        </dataSource:DataSource.GroupDescriptors>
    </dataSource:DataSource>
</xFormsListView:SfListView.DataSource>
<xFormsListView:SfListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.View>
                <StackLayout Padding="10,0,15,0">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="70*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Key}"  FontSize="18" 
                               VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                               Style="{StaticResource LabelProfileStyle}"/>
                        <buttons:SfCheckBox HorizontalOptions="End" Grid.Column="1" 
                                            IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <BoxView  HeightRequest=".5" BackgroundColor="Black" 
                              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />                                                               

                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</xFormsListView:SfListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
<xFormsListView:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                             Padding="5,0,0,0" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <buttons:SfCheckBox Text="{Binding DisplayName}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource ProfileCheckBoxStyle}"></buttons:SfCheckBox>
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</xFormsListView:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I would like to make a group header check which I could achieve the desired ability. Can any please suggest a way how I could Implement this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't see any check cox in this example?

Comment: Please, format the code properly

Comment: added expected checkbox in the group header template

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the following document for using CheckBox in the SfListView GroupHeader,
[CheckBox in SfListView GroupHeader](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/listview/grouping#checkbox-in-group-header)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `CollectionView` with `SelectionMode` of `Multiple`.

```
<CollectionView SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}">
    <xFormsListView:SfListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Padding="10,0,15,0">
                <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Text="{Binding Key}" FontSize="18" VerticalOptions="Center"
                       HorizontalOptions="Start" Style="{StaticResource LabelProfileStyle}"/>
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                </Grid>
                <BoxView HeightRequest=".5" BackgroundColor="Black" 
                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </xFormsListView:SfListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<object> SelectedItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<object>();
```

The `SelectedItems` property must be of type `ObservableCollection<object>` or it won't work. Support for custom objects is coming in Xamarin.Forms 4.6, but it doesn't exist currently. Then the user can select the items they want or you can use a check box to programmatically place items into `SelectedItems`.

Extend `CheckBox` to accept a string so you can pass the group name and know which items to place in `SelectedItems`.